# Est (le) suivant

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

*D'endetté à millionaire* de David Descôteaux :

> Toutefois, le point à retenir est **le** suivant.

Est-il possible d'omettre "le" dans cette phrase ? Je pense que non, mais l'omission devrait être possible, "suivant" serait alors un adjectif.

Answer (score 2):

Ça ne se dit pas sans l'article, non.

Une autre façon de dire dans ce cas:

> Toutefois, le point à retenir est comme suit.

---

Sans l'article, il faut quelque chose après le mot. Par exemple:

> Toutefois, le point à retenir est, suivant mon instinct, de mettre l'article.

(mais j'utiliserais plutôt *selon* dans ce cas).

Comment: Merci beaucoup.